# My program reads .txt files in Eclipse, but not when I export as .jar?

Tags: java, file, export, filepath

I have some .txt files in a folder called "progress" like this:

[image]

The program reads the files perfectly fine when I run it as a Java Application in Eclipse, but when I export it as a jar and run it, it doesn't work.  I use BufferedReader to read the .txt files, and I refer to the text files as "progress/easy1.txt", etc.  Is there something I could do to fix this?

EDIT:

I have a writer method like this:

```
public void writeToFile(String filename){

     BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

     try {

            //Construct the BufferedWriter object
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

            //Start writing to the output stream
            bufferedWriter.write("a");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //Close the BufferedWriter
            try {
                if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

So how would I incorporate the .getResourceAsStream() with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should put them in a directory within your source and access then using the classpath. See Class.getResourceAsStream() for example. This will make it work everywhere.

Comment: I edited the main post with my writeToFile() method.  How would I put in the getResourceAsStream() to work with the writer method?

Comment: So you are both reading *and* writing these files? Then the classpath thing won't work. I thought you were only reading them. If you have to read and write, then you need to pick a filename that you can access when running outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have been more clear.  So what do you mean by a filename I can access running out of Eclipse.  Like Users\Asingh\Desktop\easy1.txt or something?

Comment: Yes, consider using the user.dir or user.home [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) depending on where you want to create the file.

Comment: `user.dir` is not constant (reliable).  Use `user.home` instead.

Comment: Does `user.name` mean like for example (Mac): /Users/ASingh/
I'm using this because I'm not sure where `user.home` would be for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

My class read a file from the root folder of my project using:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
```

where filename is the name of my file (including the path of the file).

If you generate a runnable jar using eclipse selecting your class (with a main method), in my case testing.ReverseWords as "Launch Configuration" in the process and executing the jar like:

**java -cp runnable.jar testing.ReverseWords progress/B-large-practice.in**

and it find the file. I hope that help you.